# Magento get images that are only in stock

Tags: magento

I need to list thumbnail images that are only in stock but i cant find the way to insert the filter to say `addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', TRUE)` to the next code.

The structure of product:

2 Options

Color and Size

All sku's are associated to the configurable product, and Gallery image have the Color Label that Match with the Color form Option.

When you open the Configurable product in product view page, this show a dropdown or checkbox form, that allow you to select the `Color` first then Show all `Sizes` in stock. But in the dropdown show only `Colors` that are in stock.

Example:

```
Red    => S,M,L
Blue   => L,XL
Yellow => S
Gray => Not in stock, not in the dropdown.
```

Is there any way to insert a filter to skip images colors that are not saleable or in stock?

```
<?php $_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();  ?>
<?php $imgcount = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages()->count();?>
<?php if($imgcount >1): ?>
    <div class="more-views">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo html_entity_decode($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')); ?> <?php // echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>">
    <img style="padding-top:2px;" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(33, 31); ?>" width="33" height="31" alt="<?php echo html_entity_decode($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')); ?> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()); ?>" title="<?php echo html_entity_decode($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')); ?> <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()); ?>" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The images cannot be in stock (or out of stock). Only products can. Please re-factor your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi, you are right, but on product view for example, it show a dropdown with Colors that are only in stock. I edited and explained better the question. Thx